# Designing output object of RESTful service

Tags: class, rest

I am creating a new project using a REStful service. I need to send a single object containing

1. collection of object containing data for UI
2. object User( Name, role etc)
3. Collection of error occured(If any).

So I have designed my class like this

```
public class ServiceREsponse
{
 Collection<ServiceError> errorCollection { get; private set; }

    Collection<object> objectCollection { get; set; }
   User user { get; set; }
}
```

How do I populate values in this class, or how do I use this class in my service?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly the technologies / frameworks you use as client to the RESTful service. In fact, you need to instantiate your class and populate with data you want to send. Then you need to convert this object into a structure that can be put into the payload of the HTTP request.

Here is a sample:

```
PUT /myresource
(some headers like Content-Type: application/json)
{
  "objectCollection": [
    (...)
  ],
  "user": {
    (...)
  }
}
```

The service may not support all structures but formats like JSON, XML or YAML are commonly supported. With JSON, we will have something like that:

```
{
  "objectCollection": [
    { "field1": (...) },
    { "field1": (...) },
    { "field1": (...) },
    (...)
  ],
  "user": {
    "name": "my name",
    (...)
  }
}
```

You can notice that collections must be converted into arrays in the structure.

Moreover the generated structure must match the structure expected by the service.

With Java, you have some great REST client like Restlet (http://restlet.com/products/restlet-framework/) and object to/from JSON / XML / YAML like Jackson (http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonHome).

Hope it helps,
Thierry